# Using routing and redirect for prevent duplication links on the same content

Tags: php, codeigniter

Imagine we have the controller

```
class Test 
{
   public function index()
   {
     echo 'hello!';
   }
}
```

So I can call it like test/index or for the best practice set route something like $routing['test'] = 'test/index';

So now I can call it with two ways test or test/index and same page have two links! So I want to know what would be the best solution for this situation?

All that I am thinking maybe check in index if I have in segment 'index' so redirect to route just 'test'.

I working with Codeigniter but I think this is question is SEO'specific too.

**Summary:** What would be the best to prevent double linking for the same content if I use routing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wall called `.htaccess` rule stopped you. Try this way:

```
#instead of test put name of your default controller
RewriteRule ^(test(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

I found this great piece of code on [this page](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) where you can see basic but extensive `.htaccess` file for use in CI made websites / applications.

Comment: Its just on sample but I got the idea - all similar cases handle with htaccess file in one place instead of checking in every controller where I will be have same problem! Thanks!
By the way how to mark this answer like successful?